# File compare on macOS with FreeFileSync and Visual Studio Code

Tags: bash, macos, visual-studio-code

I struggling to make it work for me.

I have FreeFileSync (v10.20) and Visual Studio Code (v1.43.0) installed on macOS Mojave (v10.14.6) and would like to add a file compare context menu command, so

## Step 1:

I added Visual Studio Code to my path as explained on their site (https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/mac#_launching-from-the-command-line):

- Launch VS Code
- Open the Command Palette (F1) and type 'shell command' to find the Shell Command: Install 'code' command in PATH command.

After this, I am able to launch Terminal and run:

**code --diff**

## Step 2:

I added the following option to FreeFileSync Preferences at *'Customize context menu'*:

> Description: **Compare with Visual Studio Code**
>
> Command line: **code --diff "%local_path%" "%local_path2%"**

## The issue:

So far, it does nothing. No errors. No windows opened. Why?

Thanks for your help in advance!
Craby

Comment: doesn't just the diff command work, e.g. `diff /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2` ? In linux you can even do it side by side.

Answer (score 0):

OK, just I found out the solution myself, I hope this will help you guys, too:

The solution is to configure Visual Studio Code as external file compare (diff) tool in FreeFileSync as follows:

> Description: **Compare with Visual Studio Code**
>
> Command line: **/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron --diff "%local_path%" "%local_path2%"**

Note the \ backslashes to escape the spaces... without these it fails silently.

Enjoy!

Craby